# Prevent paper-dialog from automatically closing

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

**Hello:**

I have a `paper-dialog` element in a page:

```dart
<paper-dialog ... id="autom_desc_dialog" autoCloseDisabled> 
    ...
    <paper-button ... id="automatizar" affirmative autofocus disabled></paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
```

and I have an event listener that handles the `paper-button` click:

```dart
var auto_btn = querySelector('#automatizar');
auto_btn.on["click"].listen((Event e) {
    // Some AJAX stuff
});
```

What I want is that in some cases, to be able to prevent the dialog from closing, I've tried `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `event.stopPropagation()` but no success.

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to remove affirmative/dismissive attributes as they are used for layout. Polymer dialog docs are wrong (I've opened a GH issue) the default value for closeSelector is '[dismissive],[affirmative]' and not "", you just need to set closeSelector to "" and it won't close the dialog on clicking the buttons.

Comment: Thank you ;) yeah it really made no sense to be that complicated just to modify this simple behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `affirmative` attribute from the button then you have full control of the behavior.

#### app-element.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_dialog.dart';
/**
 * A Polymer app-element element.
 */
@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  /// Constructor used to create instance of AppElement.
  AppElement.created() : super.created() {
  }

  void openClickHandler(Event e) {
    print(e);
    ($['autom_desc_dialog'] as PaperDialog).opened = true;
  }

  void closeClickHandler(Event e){
    if(true /* some condition */) {
      ($['autom_desc_dialog'] as PaperDialog).opened = false;
    }
  }

}
```

#### app_element.html

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-dialog id="autom_desc_dialog" autoCloseDisabled>
      <div>paper dialog</div>
      <paper-button id="automatizar" autofocus label="close" on-click="{{closeClickHandler}}"></paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>

    <paper-button id="open" autofocus label="open" on-click="{{openClickHandler}}"></paper-button>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: So there is no way to prevent closing without changing the affirmative atribute anyway I like your way of making a new component =)

Comment: I don't know but I thought when you want custom behavior it would be the obvious way to remove this automatic behavior. Is there something you don't like with this approach? I don't know what you mean by `your way of making a new component`. Is there something specific? I use `pub run polymer:new_element app-element -o some_target_dir`

Comment: I think (like javascript) you would do some preventDefault() and that's it but this is an elegant solution too.

Comment: It might be possible this way too but would need some more time to debug to figure out how.