# Blank Space at bottom of Polymer Paper Dialog

Tags: dialog, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a custom polymer dialog that I use for login, this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is the code I'm using to achieve that:

```
<polymer-element name="login-dialog">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog heading="XYZ Login" vertical autoCloseDisabled="true" transition="paper-transition-center" opened="true">
      <p>{{feedback}}</p>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Username" inputValue="{{username}}" type="text"></paper-input>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Password" inputValue="{{password}}" type="password"></paper-input>

      <paper-button role="button" on-click="{{reset}}" class="noink" affirmative>
        Reset Password
      </paper-button>           
      <paper-button role="button" on-click="{{login}}" class="ink" affirmative>
        Login
      </paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="login-dialog.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I don't want the buttons to close the dialog, so I remove the affirmative from the paper buttons so that I can close the dialog myself if the correct login details were filled in.
As soon as I remove affirmative, a big white space appears at the bottom of the dialog:

[image]

Inside the dart code, I have the following for now:

```
  login(event, detail, target) {
    print("Clicked Login");

    return false;
  }

  reset(event, detail, target) {
    print("Clicked Reset");

    return false;
  }
```

I was hoping that returning false would stop the dialog from closing if I use affirmative, but it does nothing. Any ideas on how to get the buttons to no close the dialog unless I tell it to do so in the dart code and not have that white space at the bottom? (not keen on hacking it with css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning false doesn't do anything. You need to call `preventDefault()` on the event.

```dart
login(event, detail, target) {
    print("Clicked Login");

    event.preventDefault();
    // event.stopPropagation();
  }

  reset(event, detail, target) {
    print("Clicked Reset");

    event.preventDefault();
    // event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

`<paper-dialog>` has a specific option to disable automatic closing so you can `affirmative` for layout only.

```dart
<paper-dialog closeSelector="" ....
```

see also [Prevent paper-dialog from automatically closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587549)

Comment: event.preventDefault(); does nothing if the button is set to affirmative, if it's not set to affirmative, then I get the behaviour I'm looking for, but then I also get that big white gap at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried to add `stopPropagation()` (with `affirmative`), you can also try `stopImmediatePropagation()` instead.

Comment: I have indeed, it still closes the dialog. Isn't there something other than affirmative / dismissive I can use to ensure the buttons go sit where they need to sit?

Comment: Adding <paper-dialog closeSelector="" ...> fixes it, thanks Günter! If you can update your answer to include that, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, that event.preventDefault seems redundant now, works without it.

Comment: I kept it in my answer because you used `return false` in your question and that doesn't work even in cases where `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` don't work. I don't know why this doesn't work with `paper-dialog`, usually it is the way to suppress the event to be processed by other parts of the DOM.

Comment: Should I log a bug for this?